# 2 Linux OSes with 1 GRUB and a low-latency kernel

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, mate

I have Deepin OS and installed Ubuntu Mate as the third OS for recording and KXStudio addons.  When I installed Ubuntu Mate, I typed `ubiquity -b` in the terminal to avoid installing grub.  I did this because the Deepin GRUB theme is really nice (hint Ubuntu), and if I install Ubuntu with GRUB, I will lose that Deepin GRUB theme and the ubuntu GRUB will be the active one.  Then the Deepin will think it is using a GRUB but it is not "connected" and Ubuntu will use a GRUB that is connected. Since Deepin is my main driver, I want to keep it connected to its GRUB.

So right now, I have an Ubuntu grub that is not connected to the boot grub.
After install of Ubuntu Mate, I did an `update-grub` while in the Deepin terminal.  This added an Ubuntu entry to the Deepin GRUB.  After installing low latency, `update-grub` did not change anything and it still boots generic kernel when I choose Mate from the Deepin GRUB menu).

How do I manually add the low latency to the Deepin GRUB I am using now assuming GRUB is GRUB?
Normally, simply installing low latency will add it to GRUB.  But it adds it to the wrong GRUB files.

**What file do I edit and how?**
Deepin has a boot directory, `/etc/grub` and `/etc/default` folders inside the root.
 I want the Ubuntu boot menu to choose the low-latency kernel instead of generic.  (I use `uname -r` when in Mate.)
Mate also has the same boot and GRUB folders inside the root dir.

Comment: Even though you did not install grub to boot, you still should have  a /boot/grub/grub.cfg. If that has your new low-latency kernel, copy that boot stanza to Deepin's /etc/grub.d/40_custom and run `sudo update-grub`. If not you have to create your own boot stanza using new kernel. You can also edit Ubuntu's grub to match what you like as grub is grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays

Comment: @oldfred This worked.  Much appreciated!  Copy your comment answer as a real answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you did not install grub to boot, you still should have a /boot/grub/grub.cfg. 
If that has your new low-latency kernel, copy that boot stanza to Deepin's /etc/grub.d/40_custom and run sudo update-grub. If not you have to create your own boot stanza using new kernel.

More details on your own boot stanza.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Multi_002dboot-manual-config.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

You can also edit Ubuntu's grub to match what you like as grub is grub. How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Mega Forums Thread on above Custom grub screens. Best to start at last page, if interested

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays

Comment: I tried what you said and it works.  Much appreciated!  I marked this as solved.